# Understanding "let" expression in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, let

I am extremely new to lisp, had previous experience with functional programming (Haskell, SML). Why is this code returning `14`, and not `10` (i.e. `1 + 2y + 3 + 1`)?

```
(defvar x 1)

(defun g (z)
  (+ x z))

(defun f (y)
  (+ (g 1)
     (let ((x (+ y 3)))
        (g (+ y x)))))

(f 2)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you used `(DEFVAR X 1)`, which declares `X` to be a global special variable. This then causes every other later binding of `X` to use dynamic binding: here in `(LET ((X ...`.

**Style & Convention in Lisp**

Convention in Lisp: use `*X*` instead of `X` for special variables.

```
(defvar *x* 1)
```

Your code then is:

```
(defvar *x* 1)   ; global special variable *X*

(defun g (z)
  (+ *x* z))     ; use special variable *X*

(defun f (y)
  (+ (g 1)
     (let ((x (+ y 3)))    ; lexical binding of X
        (g (+ y x)))))     ; use lexical binding of X
```

run:

```
? (f 2)
10
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that you are using a Lisp dialect with [dynamic binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Binding.html#Dynamic-Binding) (link to a good description of this from the Emacs Lisp documentation).

In detail, your program behaves the way it does is because the new binding for `x` created by the `let` expression takes the place of the `(defvar x 1)` when `g` is called from within the `let` expression. So, instead of adding 1 to its argument, the `g` function adds the current value of `x`, which is 5 when inside the `let` expression.

Comment: How do you know this is elisp? This is valid common-lisp as well.

Comment: @Sylwester: I don't know it is elisp, but that was the first documentation page I found that explained dynamic binding succinctly.